# Press enter and show another paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

How to make a javascript coding, when I press "ENTER" too the input `type="text"`, it will show another paragraph `p`.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("key");
btn.onkeypress = function(e){
  if(e.keyCode === 13){
   e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="key" placeholder="south">
```

Comment: see the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wyoym85a/1/   Are you like this method

Comment: why would you be typing in an input and have the need to see a paragraph  when pressing enter?  Seems like that would be a usability issue.  Do you also show this paragraph when the form is submitted?

Comment: I'm making a simple text-based game .. with html, js, css (assignment) .. I don't know much about javascript, so here I'm

Comment: @prasad that is good enough .. but I would like it to hide my current paragaph, and show another paragraph .. I'm trying to make a simple text-based game .. I got the answer already, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/wyoym85a/4/).**

It will be better to use a `class` hidden for example to hide/show your element :

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("key");

btn.onkeypress = function(e){

  if(e.keyCode === 13){
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("my-paragraph").classList.remove("hidden");
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="key" placeholder="south">
<p id="my-paragraph" class='hidden'>Hidden paragraph</p>
```

---

But you could also use inline-style `display`  to show/hide elements, check basic example below.

Hope this helps.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("key");

btn.onkeypress = function(e){

  if(e.keyCode === 13){
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("my-paragraph").style.display='block';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="key" placeholder="south">
<p id="my-paragraph" style='display:none'>Hidden paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamically paragraph and add the text inside it:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("key");
var div = document.getElementById("paragraphs");
btn.onkeypress = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        var newParagraph = document.createElement('p');
        newParagraph.textContent = btn.value;
        div.appendChild(newParagraph);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="key" placeholder="south">
<div id="paragraphs">

</div>
```

Comment: Be careful the OP ask how to _show another paragraph `p`_... not how to _create dynamically paragraph and add the text inside it_.